# Linear transformation problem involving the intersection of the range and nullify of T

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be finite dimensional and suppose $T : V \rightarrow V$ is linear.
Prove if the range of $T \cap \text{null space}$ of $T = \{0\}$, then range of $T + \text{null space of } T = V$.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem? Should I use the rank and nullity theorem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use the rank nullity theorem.

**Hint:** for spaces $U$ and $V$, we generally have
$$
\dim(U+V) \leq \dim(U) + \dim(V)
$$
when are the two sides equal?

---

Let $B = \{u_1,\dots,u_r\}$ and $C = \{v_1,\dots,v_s\}$ be bases for the range and null space of $T$ respectively.  Note that $r$ is the range, and $s$ is the dimension of the null space, so we know that $r + s = \dim(V)$.

Consider the set $B \cup C$.  Show that this is a set of linearly independent vectors.  Note that it is a basis of both (range of $T$) + (null space of $T$) and a basis for all of $V$.  Thus, the two spaces must be equal.

Comment: Can u explain it  slightly more.I am not getting the proof sir

Comment: Let $U$ be the range and $V$ the null-space.  What does the rank nullity theorem tell you about their dimensions?  Can you answer the question given from my hint?

Comment: dim U+dim V=dim of the vector space.But I cant answer from here

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: Please see my method $dim(Im T+Ker T)=dim(Im T)+dim(Ker T)-dim(Im T\cap Ker T) \rightarrow dim(Im T+Ker T)=dim V.$

Comment: I don't see your answer

Comment: What to do next?

Comment: If you have that formula, then it is sufficient to note that $\dim(\text{Im}(T) \cap \ker(T)) = 0$